# maven test does not run with External Jar

Tags: maven, selenium, testng, maven-plugin

Maven project which has one of the External jar imported,

Project(mvn test) run successfully as defined for @Test class, if there is no external jar refer to Project.

But It can not run (mvn test) if there is external Jar available in the project.

[image]

Is there any plugin or reference which can invoke for mvn test with reference to be work with external jar ?

Comment: Why won't you add this external JAR as maven dependency ?

Comment: You can keep external jar in the your project folder and point it though maven pom file

Comment: Is there any specific usecase for keeping external JAR ?

Comment: @AutomatedOwl , cruisepandey To record video script, I do use atutestrecorder jar as external, which has not mvn dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
    -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

first add the external jar to .m2 repository by following above code in command prompt.

> *Second method:*

add the external jar information to the pom.xml file directly as shown below ,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>your external jar groupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>your jar artifactid</artifactId>
    <version>version of your external jar</version>
    <scope>system</scope>//this should be system only 
    <systemPath>C:/Users/Desktop/external.jar</systemPath>// path of the external jar.
</dependency>
```

Thereby you can add the external jar to maven repository in your system.and when maven tries to load the dependencies it will load the External jar to your project from locally inspite of maven central repository.

Comment: Linked helped me to reach target, https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html  
I have added jar through command line by this simple command "mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DpomFile=<path-to-pomfile>" Updated maven Project, and It run as expected